# Win7 and Ubuntu refuse to coexist

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, grub2, bootloader

I'll make this quick: I have an HP laptop with win7, I installed Ubuntu on a separate partition, and when I tried to boot win7 from grub I got the loading screen and no progress-ever. I did a /fixmbr with the windows recovery cd and got back windows, but wiped out grub and my access to Ubuntu. I reinstalled grub from the Ubuntu live usb ( I know I did this correctly) and now windows won't boot, again.

I'm a linux noob at a loss. Your wisdom is greatly appreciated!

---

Update in response to Scott Severance:

your instructions say to determine the main partition on my computer. I'm not sure what this means... my windows partition is at sda2, my boot partition is at sda1, and my linux root partition is at sda7... Which is the "main" partition?

UPDATE: I determined that you were probably referring to the linux root(/) partition, because this was the only partition for which I could follow your instructions without errors. Now, Windows is booting fine (thanks to /fixmbr), but even after the grub instructions there is no grub. It boots straight into windows.

Comment: Now you can log in into your ubuntu right then got software center and search for the boot repair and install it other wise "sudo apt-get install boot-repair-ubuntu" enter above command in the terminal and use that to restore the grub this time you will get both windows7 and ubuntu

Comment: i have faced the same problem this boot repair solved me that so try it

Comment: Unregistered and new users have limited commenting privileges. The best way is to edit your question (as I've done for you). Even better would be to register.

Comment: Have you run `update-grub` from within a `chroot` environment? If you've got a separate boot partition, you need to mount it first. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you said that you know that you updated Grub correctly, I'm pretty sure that you didn't; else you wouldn't be having these problems. You may have followed the instructions you found exactly, but those instructions might have been wrong.

Run the Windows `fixmbr` again, then use the live CD to set up a `chroot` environment and run `update-grub` from there. I've [posted instructions previously](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/13398).

Note that if you've got a separate `/boot` partition, you need to mount it after mounting your root partition and before entering the `chroot`:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

If after doing this Grub still doesn't play nicely with Windows, it probably means that your Grub configuration is messed up. Go back to your `chroot` environment and reinstall the grub packages. Hopefully, that'll clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar enough with Windows-7 as I switched to Ubuntu before it came out. All I know is if 7 needs to defrag like previous versions, you should do that before trying to install Ubuntu beside it.

Comment: Maybe you should defrag, but it's impossible for not defragging to cause the original issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 Bootloader is a bit tacky at times. I would suggest Use a tool like EasyBCD 
Click [here](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)! and njoy!!

regards,

Mrugesh Mohapatra

Comment: could you improve your answer by placing part of answer ?